# Парсинг json golang

Tags: json, парсер, golang

Здравствуйте.
Есть json:

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "01ae6145-90a3-11e7-7a69-8f55000cda4b",
            "accountId": "8757f3bf-8504-11e7-7a69-971100001fef",
            "minimumBalance": 1000.0,
            "modificationsCount": 0,
            "isSerialTrackable": false,
            "stock": 1450.0,
            "reserve": 60.0,
            "inTransit": 0.0,
            "quantity": 1390.0
        }
    ]
}
```

как вывести на печать значение "id" без круглых и квадратных скобок?
что бы не

```
[{01ae6145-90a3-11e7-7a69-8f55000cda4b}]
```

А просто

```
01ae6145-90a3-11e7-7a69-8f55000cda4b
```

Пробовал вот так: не вышло
https://goplay.space/#-cOCcsz4d3

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type mmn struct {
    Rows []RowsP
}
type RowsP struct {
    ID string
}

func main() {
    body1 := []byte(`{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "01ae6145-90a3-11e7-7a69-8f55000cda4b",
            "accountId": "8757f3bf-8504-11e7-7a69-971100001fef",
            "minimumBalance": 1000.0,
            "modificationsCount": 0,
            "isSerialTrackable": false,
            "stock": 1450.0,
            "reserve": 60.0,
            "inTransit": 0.0,
            "quantity": 1390.0
        }
    ]
}`)
    var app = mmn{}
    err1 := json.Unmarshal(body1, &app)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal("error")
    }

    fmt.Println(app.Rows)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы печатаете слайс из единственной структуры RowsP. Берите эту структуру из слайса и обращайтесь к его полю ID.
    fmt.Println(app.Rows[0].ID)

Само собой перед этим проверяйте, что слайс не пустой, а то будет паника.

Comment: Ваш ответ конечно уморительный, я даже себя стариком почувствовал который от телефонное вибрации креститься начинает. Но все же... меньше сленга, не забывайте ваш ответ могут читать и новички.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, поле структуры, слайс и паника - это база. Объяснять базу в ответе не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Пример.

Сервис для ленивых как я https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Далее вот так https://goplay.space/#h6OKmndwLd

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

// used https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/
type mmn struct {
    Rows []struct {
        ID                 string  `json:"id"`
        AccountID          string  `json:"accountId"`
        MinimumBalance     float64 `json:"minimumBalance"`
        ModificationsCount int     `json:"modificationsCount"`
        IsSerialTrackable  bool    `json:"isSerialTrackable"`
        Stock              float64 `json:"stock"`
        Reserve            float64 `json:"reserve"`
        InTransit          float64 `json:"inTransit"`
        Quantity           float64 `json:"quantity"`
    } `json:"rows"`
}

func main() {
    body1 := []byte(`{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "01ae6145-90a3-11e7-7a69-8f55000cda4b",
            "accountId": "8757f3bf-8504-11e7-7a69-971100001fef",
            "minimumBalance": 1000.0,
            "modificationsCount": 0,
            "isSerialTrackable": false,
            "stock": 1450.0,
            "reserve": 60.0,
            "inTransit": 0.0,
            "quantity": 1390.0
        }
    ]
}`)
    var app = mmn{}
    err1 := json.Unmarshal(body1, &app)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal("error")
    }

    // итерируем 
    for _, row := range app.Rows {
        fmt.Println(row.ID)
    }

}
```

Удачи